# Get name of file that is double-clicked on to launch a macOS app

Tags: macos, cocoa

I have developed a macOS app which will allow the app to be launched if the user double-clicks on a file with my defined file extension. The file extension association was done inside the Info.plist file. I am able to double-click a file to launch my app successfully. However, I can't seem to find out how I can get the name of the file that was used to launch the app.

The file name does not seem to be stored as part of `argv`. In my app I would like to be able to get the name of the file, perform some initialization code, and then open the file in my app environment.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Implement the `NSApplicationDelegate` method `func application(_ sender: NSApplication, openFile filename: String) -> Bool` or `func application(_ sender: NSApplication, openFiles filenames: [String])`. This is called when your app is asked to open a file (or launched for a file).